# Express app.all interfering with API calls

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm building a MEAN app and Angular is handling any routes that are defined by the client such as '/profile', '/stream' etc.

Because I'm using HTML5Mode in Angular, I've had to add the following to my express config to allow clean URLs to be accessed and input from browser URL bar:

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile('views/dashboard.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

This however is now interfering with my API and any API calls are returned blank, so for example if I visit users/active/profile which should return a JSON response of the current user's details, the browser redirects you to the homepage.

Answer (score 2):

Express will handle the requests URLs(routes) in the order you declared them, since `*` is an exception to all other previous route declarations you need to move this code to the end of your routes:

```
  /** this needs to be your last route **/
    app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile('views/dashboard.html', { root: __dirname });
    });
```

Comment: When I move it to the end of the file this then breaks the routing and the angular entry point no longer gets recognised.

Comment: This answer seems to be correct except one thing: `app.all` should be declared *before* error handling middleware, if it is present in your code.